# How to chain python and S3 commands in Docker CMD?

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to chain multiple commands in `Dockerfile` using the CMD.
I have 2 python scripts that needs to run in sequence and then I am doing an S3 sync of the files that these 2 scripts created.

My docker Command:

```
CMD [ "python", "code/py_script1.py", "&&" ,"code/py_script2.py", "&&", "aws s3 sync /files s3://test_container/test/"]
```

The first script runs successfully and then the container terminates. I am not sure how can I chain the commands.

I am okay with passing these commands as command line arguments.
Is there a way that I could create a .sh file, put all these commands and simply execute the .sh file which will take care of running these commands in sequence.

Please suggest if there is any better, more efficient way as well. Thank you.

Comment: create a entrypoint.sh file  with all these commands and run the shell script in the CMD

Comment: also if you are in need of a full blown prod system where you have more complex workflows, have a look at celery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create a `.sh` script and simply use it in Docker. Suppose you already have the shell script in the same folder as `Dockerfile`. Add following two lines to `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY path/to/your-shell-script.sh /your-shell-script.sh
CMD [ "/your-shell-script.sh" ]
```

To run command sequentially, you can use either `set -e` or `&&`. I prefer `set -e`.

```shell
#! /bin/sh
set -e

python code/py_script1.py
python code/py_script2.py
aws s3 sync /files s3://test_container/test/
```

`&&` version:

```shell
#! /bin/sh

python code/py_script1.py && \
python code/py_script2.py && \
aws s3 sync /files s3://test_container/test/
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I make sure that all the commands are executed in sequential order. I am not a pro in shell scripting, but If i just add the new commands in new line, will that work ?